# Loading a Transient collection JPA & Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I have two entities department & Employee where multiple employees are tied to a department.

```
@Entity
class Department {

    @Id
    private Long dept_id;

    @JoinColumn("dept_id")
    private set<Employee> employeeList;

    @Transient
    private set<Employee> managerList;

    @Transient
    private set<Employee> developerList;

    //getters & Setters
}


@Entity
class Employee {

    @Id
    private Long emp_id;

    private Department department;

    @column
    private String emp_type; //Developer,Manager etc etc

    //Other details, Getters and setters

}
```

To load those two transient variables, in JPA we can use the callback methods and load it by iterating the employeeList. But is it possible to use a native Hibernate @Formula for loading those entities.

@Formula(select e from employee e where type='dev') should work. But without specifying a new query, something along the lines of setting a filter condition and loading those transient fields.

Is it possible?

Comment: Why are those fields transient? Is it some lazy load trick?

Comment: A suggestion. As you want to access the same collection by type, use a Map.  `@OneToMany(mappedBy="departament")@MapKey(name"emp_type")Map<String, Employee> mapByType`

Comment: @pirho: No. Table will have all the employees regardless of their employment type. I am trying to fetch them with different types

Comment: @HenriqueFernandesCipriano: That probably should work. A good suggestion. Though is there a way to achieve what I am thinking?

Comment: I am not sure what you're after but I might inherit `Employee` by type and then declare `private set<EmployeeOfCorrectType> developerList;`.